# Can I remove user's home directory folders?

Tags: macos, finder, folders, symlink

I have the following scenario:

All of my files, documents etc. are saved on Copy.com.

I have installed copy on my MacBooc Air all my files went to the following directory:

```
/Users/username/Copy
/Users/username/Copy/Documents
/Users/username/Copy/Movies
/Users/username/Copy/Pictures
/Users/username/Copy/Music
/Users/username/Copy/Workspace
```

On my Mac's home folder, I want to replace the following folders with symlinks or aliases to the Copy ones:

```
/Users/username
/Users/username/Documents (alias to /Users/username/Copy/Documents)
/Users/username/Movies (alias to ...)
/Users/username/Pictures (alias to ...)
/Users/username/Music (alias to ...)
/Users/username/Workspace (alias to ...)
```

I have tried to delete a folder under `/Users/username` and Mac prompts:

> “Documents” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by OS X.

I have done this scenario on Ubuntu, that's why I want it on MacBook Air, too.

Comment: That's possible, I've made something similiar on my machine. However You'll loose directory icons (for example in Finder left pane). There's also a posibility to change Your home folder location, would this be good for You?

Comment: I found the answer to my question at: 
http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25947/90213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finder will prevent you from deleting the default directories, but Terminal won't. You can use `rm -rf /path/to/directory` to delete the folder then [create the symlink](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115646/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-in-terminal/115647#115647) normally.