# Install OS X Applications and Library directories on external drive

Tags: macos, applications, library

Wondering how could I set some sort of partial OS X installation on an external drive, I searched Google only to find that I may be the only one looking for this.
The goal is to get both the Applications and Library directories (those from OS X installation's root, not user's) to run them on any Mac, always keeping the applications' preferences in the Library directory, on the drive.

You may see that as some sort of partial OS X installation.

Is this possible and, if so, how ?

Comment: I assume you want to make some portable setup where you plugin the external drive in different macs and want your settings transferred like this? Only moving the Library folder to an external drive is not possible (as far as I know), but you can move the [whole home folder](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25933/24324)

Comment: Not exactly. I try to get just the opposite of this [Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1164891/keeping_mac_os_and_data_on_separate_drives.html) except that I would just keep the Applications and Library directories. I think I could launch the install and try to force the Install OS X application to recognise the external drive as the main drive and put the Home folder on the Mac's internal drive but I don't own any spare Mac to try this out and won't risk my current setting for this manoeuvre.